# AES 128 in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

I don't know why when I encrypt in AES a text with the PyCrypto (Crypto.Cipher- AES), the result isn't the same as the ciphertext generate by a code in C.

For example, the following code gives me

```
99756ed0115f676cef45ae25937bfd63247358a80803dde3fc1eae4953ee7277
```

instead of

```
CC613A0BDC930DABEA7A26126CE489EA
```

here is my code:

```
key = '1F61ECB5ED5D6BAF8D7A7068B28DCC8E'
IV = 16 * '\x00'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
encryptor = AES.new(key, mode, IV=IV)
text = '020ABC00ABCDEFf8d500000123456789'
ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)
print binascii.hexlify(ciphertext)
```

Comment: Please show how the text is being encrypted from C.

Comment: If you use the sample vectors from the FIPS-197 AES Standard do you get the correct result?  http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf   Note you may have to test with Electronic Code Book Mode (ECB) to make sure your mode does not change the outcome.  Though ECB Mode should not be used in any end product

Comment: AES is a block cipher meaning a short cleartext will be padded out to 128 bits or 256 bits before encrypting. The output you don't like is exactly 256 bits, which is a proper length; the output of your C program is 128 bits long. The two libraries have different default block sizes. This is independent of key length.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to `unhexlify` both the key and text (example in IPython using Python 3);

```
In [1]: from Crypto.Cipher import AES

In [2]: import binascii

In [3]: import os

In [4]: key = binascii.unhexlify('1F61ECB5ED5D6BAF8D7A7068B28DCC8E')

In [5]: IV = os.urandom(16)

In [6]: binascii.hexlify(IV).upper()
Out[6]: b'3C118E12E1677B8F21D4922BE4B2398E'

In [7]: encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=IV)

In [8]: text = binascii.unhexlify('020ABC00ABCDEFf8d500000123456789')

In [9]: ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)

In [10]: print(binascii.hexlify(ciphertext).upper())
b'2133D236609558353F7C501E6EBBB8D9
```

**Edit:** As André Caron correctly states in the comments, it is generally a [bad idea](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto) to use an IV consisting of only zeroes. I've changed the code to use a random IV. Note that the IV should also be communicated to the receiver; it is needed for decryption. Often the IV is prepended to the ciphertext.

Comment: Thanks Roland for your answer. You're right, I forgot to convert the hexadecimals values.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend propagating use of a null initialization vector.  Python has built-in support for cryptographic-safe generation of random bytes with [os.urandom()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom).  We should update the answer to use something like `IV = os.urandom(16)`.

Comment: @AndréCaron A very good point. Updated to include a random IV.